# parsing the file using touch xml in iphone

Tags: iphone

```
<ArrayOfBar xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BarometerModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Bar>
    <BarId>1</BarId>
    <BarType>Pub</BarType>
    <Location>West Ocean City</Location>
    <LocationId>1</LocationId>
    <Name>Mickey Fine Bar & Grill</Name>
    <Phone>9884020844</Phone>
    <Rating>3.50</Rating>
    <Status>Open</Status>
    <TypeId>1</TypeId>
    <Website>www.mickeyfinebar.com</Website>
  </Bar>
</ArrayOfBar>`
```

how to parse this file using touch XML?

and this is the code I am using:

```
-(void) grabRSSFeed:(NSString *)blogAddress {

// Initialize the blogEntries MutableArray that we declared in the header
blogEntries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];    

// Convert the supplied URL string into a usable URL object
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: blogAddress];

// Create a new rssParser object based on the TouchXML "CXMLDocument" class, this is the
// object that actually grabs and processes the RSS data
CXMLDocument *rssParser = [[[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:nil] autorelease];

// Create a new Array object to be used with the looping of the results from the rssParser
NSArray *resultNodes = NULL;

// Set the resultNodes Array to contain an object for every instance of an  node in our RSS feed
resultNodes = [rssParser nodesForXPath:@"//Bar" error:nil];

// Loop through the resultNodes to access each items actual data
for (CXMLElement *resultElement in resultNodes) {

    // Create a temporary MutableDictionary to store the items fields in, which will eventually end up in blogEntries
    NSMutableDictionary *blogItem = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    // Create a counter variable as type "int"
    int counter;

    // Loop through the children of the current  node
    for(counter = 0; counter < [resultElement childCount]; counter++) {

        // Add each field to the blogItem Dictionary with the node name as key and node value as the value
        [blogItem setObject:[[resultElement childAtIndex:counter] stringValue] forKey:[[resultElement childAtIndex:counter] name]];
    }

    // Add the blogItem to the global blogEntries Array so that the view can access it.
    [blogEntries addObject:[blogItem copy]];
}
```

}

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [blogEntries count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

// Set up the cell
int blogEntryIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] -1];
cell.textLabel.text=[[blogEntries objectAtIndex: blogEntryIndex] objectForKey: @"BarId"];
return cell;
}
```

can any one please help me how to parse it?

Answer (score 6):

```
CXMLDocument *rssParser = [[[CXMLDocument alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url options:0  error:nil]autorelease];

NSArray *items = [rssParser nodesForXPath:@"//Bar" error:nil];
for (CXMLElement *resultElement in items) {
    Data  *objData = [[Data alloc] init];

    NSArray *BarIds = [resultElement elementsForName:@"BarId"];
    for (CXMLElement *id in BarIds) {
        objData.id = id.stringValue;
        break;
    }
    NSArray *Types = [resultElement elementsForName:@"Type"];
    for (CXMLElement *Type in Types) {
        objData.type = Type.stringValue;
        break;
    }
            NSArray *Locations = [resultElement elementsForName:@"Location"];
    for (CXMLElement *Location in Locations) {
        objData.type = Location.stringValue;
        break;
    }...
```

Using this you can fetch data from the **XML file using TuochXML** and than save that **objData as Array object**... and use it to represent in Table.

Might be this is useful to you